# mvn clean install building but not running the test scripts

Tags: maven

`mvn clean test` is building the maven project but not running test scripts.

I also tried all goals like `mvn clean install`.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What do your test scripts look like?

Comment: Please update with the project layout. You need to have tests in the right folder with the right naming convention with the testing framework probably (Junit) in the test dependencies.

Comment: here is my testng.xml building but not runing :(

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.k2js.testrunner.Openurl"/>
    </classes>